# Google Guice and JPA Injection - Strange error

Tags: java, servlets, jpa, jersey, guice

Im currently working on a JPA Jersey Servlet and Im trying to use Guice for dependency injection. The Problem is, that I get the following error:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) null returned by binding at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule.configurePersistence(JpaPersistModule.java:63)
 but parameter 1 of com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.<init>() is not @Nullable
  while locating java.util.Properties annotated with @com.google.inject.persist.jpa.Jpa()
   for parameter 1 at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.<init>(JpaPersistService.java:43)
 at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule.configurePersistence(JpaPersistModule.java:67)
 while locating com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService
   for field at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.emProvider(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:33)
 at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule.configurePersistence(JpaPersistModule.java:76)

2) null returned by binding at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule.configurePersistence(JpaPersistModule.java:63)
 but parameter 1 of com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.<init>() is not @Nullable
  while locating java.util.Properties annotated with @com.google.inject.persist.jpa.Jpa()
    for parameter 1 at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.<init>(JpaPersistService.java:43)
  at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule.configurePersistence(JpaPersistModule.java:67)
  while locating com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService
  while locating com.google.inject.persist.UnitOfWork 
    for field at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.unitOfWork(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:36)
  at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistModule.configurePersistence(JpaPersistModule.java:76)
2 errors
```

The code that i generating this error is:

```
install(new JpaPersistModule("theseen")); 
filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);
```

If I use the "standard" way by instantiating a EntitiManager and uncommenting these lines, nothing happens.

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("theseen");
 EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

 em.getTransaction().begin();
 em.merge(s);
 em.getTransaction().commit();
```

works like a charm. So I think the setup if the database connection must be ok.

What could these to errors possibly be? I tested the same App on another test environment and it works! Both machines use Glassfish 3.1, Eclipse Indigo with m2eclipse and m2wtp integration. I use Guice 3.0 with guice-persist 3.0 and guice-servlet 3.0. The machine where the app is working runs Ubuntu 11.04 with OpenJDK, the machine where problems occure uses Windows 7 with JDK1.6v26. I normally use a Datasource provided by Glassfish, but even using a plain persistence.xml is not working.

I am seriously confused...
Any ideas what is wrong with Guice Injection for JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody answered I went brute force:

Completely reinstall Glassfish and the WebApp worked...

Something must have been corrupted during the long months of testing here on my local machine.

Comment: I revently discovered that google closure template jar turns guice upside down by mixing guice 2.0 with guice 3.0...that makes using both impossible...

Comment: Your comment really helped! Had the very same error and the cause was that I was using an older version of TestNG along with guice 3 in a maven build. That old TestNG jar had guice 2 inside... Replaced it with the latest TestNG version and the tests run again. Thanks again for giving my the right direction!!